# Correct Way to Hook jQuery Script in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress site and have a .js file that I would like linked up so I can call the script. After much research, I've found this must be done with a hook in functions.php. I've tried all sorts of variations but cannot get the official method to work, but I have found a way that does work but just breaks the rest of the site in the process.

What am I doing wrong? I know about the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` & `get_template_directory_uri()` differences with parent and child themes but neither seem to make any difference.

Here's the 'official' way that doesn't work:

```
function add_jquery_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'http://<site>.com/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/custom-scripts.js', // this is the location of your script file
     array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
  );
}
```

The 'not recommended at all' way that works but breaks the rest of the site:

```
function add_jquery_script() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<site>/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/custom-scripts.js"></script>' . "\n";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_jquery_script');
```

As always, any help much appreciated. Thanks guys

**UPDATE**

After echoing out `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` I can see that my URL needs to be relative, which should now be as follows, however it still will not work.

```
function add_jquery_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-scripts.js', // this is the location of your script file
     array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
  );
}
```

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work' what do you mean, does it flag a php/javascript/header error, does the script link output but won't call, is the output wrong, in wrong place, what?

Comment: @Edward It doesn't do anything. It's as if the script doesn't get called. I've just realised my URL should be relative after an echo on  `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` but even now it still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: OK - so fails silently, have you got error reporting on? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Edward I've just added that line above the function and it hasn't reported any errors. It's just occurred to me... the script I'm using doesn't actually call the function `add_jquery_script()` after creating the function - Please don't tell me I've been that dumb!?

Comment: Well, i was getting to that, haha, erm, the function would need to be called to execute, yes. That can be hard to find sometimes, especially in someone else's framework, so no, your not dumb.

Comment: @Edward Yep I've been that dumb! OMG I've spent over 15 hours trying to get that to work! However it is still breaking the rest of the site - I.e, other things aren't showing up anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61691/discussion-between-ryan-and-edward).

Comment: 'other things'? haha, pictures of naked ladies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PHP

You need to call the function `add_jquery_script();` before it can be expect to output anything - pretty simple, easily forgotten.

## JQuery

The script was breaking your code because of a reference error, `var price` definition should be moved inside the function so it is in the function's `scope`.
http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    refresh();
    $('#bittrex-price').load(bittrexPrice);
});

function refresh() {
    var price = "[domain hidden]/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php";
    setTimeout(function (price) {
        $('#bittrex-price').fadeOut('slow').load(price, params).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#bittrex-vol').fadeOut('slow').load(price, params2).fadeIn('fast');
        refresh();
    }, 1000);
}
```